# Adding Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I am getting confused on adding Fibonacci numbers. For example I know that:

$\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K+1}+\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K}=\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K+2}$

But I believe my logic is flawed. The way I am thinking about this is that if you add $\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K+1}$ to $\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K}$ it would become $\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K+2}$ because you have added a $\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K}$. **I do not understand why or how the following is true**
$\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K}+\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K-1}=\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K+1}$

Comment: The last one, with the $K-1,$ is false

Comment: $F_K + F_{K-1} = F_{k+1}$

Comment: Sorry Typo! It should have been $\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K+1}$. I still do not understand why. If you rearrange the definition you would get $\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K-1}=\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K}+\mathrm{F}_\mathrm{K-2}$. Given that i just do not see the transformation.

Comment: Take your first one but  with $K = M-1,$ begins $F_{K+1} + F_K = F_{K+2},$ next $F_M + F_ {M-1} = F_{M+1}.$

Answer (score 2):

Let me restate what you know.  You know that
$$
F_{k+1} + F_k = F_{k+2} \tag{1}
$$
**for any** integer $k$.  That means that in particular, if $l$ is any integer, you can let $k = l - 1$ and you get
$$
F_{(l-1) + 1} + F_{(l-1)} = F_{(l-1) + 2}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
F_l + F_{l-1} = F_{l+1}
$$
Since the variable name doesn't matter, we can replace $l$ with $k$, as long as we keep in mind that this $k$ is different than the $k$ we had before. So we get
$$
F_k + F_{k-1} = F_{k+1}. \tag{2}
$$

**In summary:** The identity you don't understand (2) is just the same thing as (1), except it is shifted over by one.

Answer (score 0):

The efinition of Fibonacci numbers is:
$$
\begin{align}
F_{k} &= F_{k-1} + F_{k-2}, k \ge 2 \\
F_0 &= 0 \\
F_1 &= 1
\end{align}
$$
where $k$ is an integer.

Everything else you write about them can be inferred from that.

Of course, assuming $K \ge 0$, writing $F_{K+2} = F_{K+1} + F_K$ is equivalent to above, which means it's right simply by definition. Your second statement, however, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let $l=k-1$.  Then $F_{k+2} = F_{k+1} + F_k$ is the same as $F_{l+1}=F_l + F_{l-1}$.

When you are confused by something like this, it is usually best to try specific values.  For example, why is $F_{3-1} = F_{3} + F_{3-1}$ true?

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it clear what "$F_n$" denotes. n represents which term it is in the sequence. For example, $F_6$ is the sixth term in the sequence. $F_{n+1}$ means the term $1$ after the $n $th term in the sequence.

Also, it is vital that we understand what the Fibonacci series is:

> Each term is equal to the sum of the previous two terms

$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n $ just means that the sum of a term and the term directly after is the term after that one.

You stated that $F_n + F_{n-1}=F_{n+1}$

That is correct.

In word form, it says this term add the previous one is the after it.